# Can you use Thunderbolt storage if host only supports usbc with some adapters?

Tags: usb-c, thunderbolt

I've got a problem with my PC only supporting ubsc but not thunderbolt and all my external storage being thunderbolt 3 ssd storage.

I didnt realize that they are not backwards compatible from TB -> ubsc while Thunderbolt supported host can handle usbc...

Is there anything i can do, like an adapter that translates thunderbolt into usbc so the PC still deals with usbc... i dont necessarily care if the storage speed will be slower.

UPDATE

I've got thunderbolt 3 storage and regarding usb type c i'm not sure about the version but this is the board (specs simply say gen 2) https://www.asus.com/id/motherboards-components/motherboards/tuf-gaming/tuf-gaming-b550m-plus-wi-fi/

Comment: What version of Thunderbolt. Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound `all my external storage being thunderbolt 3 ssd storage`

Comment: What about the Type-C port? What version of USB is it?

Comment: updated, i hope there is some way to do this, device connects, windows basically says your hardware does not support thunderbolt 3 but i'd imagine there is a software or hardware (as adapter) solution for this...

Comment: Given you have a AMD motherboard there is no way to connect a Thunderbolt 3 device to your computer Only USB 4 and Thunderbolt 4 would be possible, you might be able to add an USB 4 PCIe card, but if your doing that you might as well add a Thunderbolt 3 card instead.

Comment: As far as I can remember you can't add TB support simply by adding a corresponding card since the card requires support from the CPU/motherboard/platform to work. I might be wrong though and no idea if the game has changed with USB4 and/or TB4. (I do wonder if the PCIe tunneling thing and/or TB3 backward compatibility is even *technically possible* with a card/controller from e.g. ASMedia.)

Comment: wow i had no idea amd = no thunderbolt
most seriously fast storage is TB3 (i have not even seen a TB4 device)
damn this sucks